# What does it mean to receive "call to a member function save() on a non-object" during Magento SalesOrderAddComment?

Tags: php, magento

I'm calling SalesOrderAddComment for the purposes of updating the Magento order's status. The weird thing is that I'm only receiving this error when I call this method for a particular instance of Magento; this code works when pointing at any other Magento we try so we're assuming it's some configuration issue. Here's the code:

```
public eCommerceResponse UpdateOrderStatus(string orderId, string status)
    {
        eCommerceResponse ret = DataHelpers.createBaseResponse();
            salesOrderAddCommentResponse result = _client.salesOrderAddComment(new salesOrderAddCommentRequest
            {
                orderIncrementId = orderId,
                sessionId = _session,
                status = status
            });
        return ret;
    }
```

I've verified with the customer that their database contains the statuses that we're trying to update to.

The customer who owns this Magento also has the Amasty extension installed on their Magento, which I know has some of its own special order statuses. I'm gathering that this error is more of a general error that can be thrown with PHP, something I'm not familiar with at all, if the object is null (certainly correct me if I'm wrong here). I'm wondering if Magento could be trying to retrieve information on the status I've submitted in the request, not returning something in an internal method because Amasty has modified something, and then throwing the error.

I'm not amazingly familiar with Magento so I'll provide any clarification if necessary.

Comment: What are the magento versions of all the instances that you are checking? Do they differ?

Comment: They are all using either version 1.12 or 1.13 of the API.